# Escape backward slash in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Is it possible to make a call to web API that accepts string to escape backward slash?

The syntax for call is `/api/testapi/PostSomeData/{ID}/{text}`. `text` may be URL, file path or just some text. If the `text` is URL or any text my program works fine. If it is file path like `file:///C:/TestDirec` or `\\\\ServerName\\SomeData\\dinosaur.jpg` then it fails.

```
http://localhost:12/api/testapi/PostSomeData/1/file:///C:/TestDirec
```

also my WebApiConfig file looks like this

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "Api",
                 routeTemplate: "api/testapi/{action}/{ID}/{FilePath}",
                 defaults: new { Controller = "testapi", ID = @"\d+", FilePath =@"\d+" }
             );
```

Controller code is

```
        [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
        public void PostSomeData(int ID, string FilePath)
        {
        }
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `WebUtility.UrlEncode` or `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("file:///C:/TestDirec")
```

it will return `file%3a%2f%2f%2fC%3a%2fTestDirec` which is a valid string to use in a url.

Comment: But my call is http://localhost:12/api/testapi/PostSomeData/1/file:///C:/TestDirec. I type in this url.

Comment: @newbieCSharp try this http://google.com?q=file%3a%2f%2f%2fC%3a%2fTestDirec What is displayed in the textbox?

Comment: that works. I added more code for clarity. Call to this web api does not work with url encoded

Comment: @newbieCSharp Describe "does not work". Does it actually contact the right URL when you watch it with debugging tools? Does it throw an error?

Comment: I get Server Error in '/' Application.Http 400 error when I execute in fiddler